# django rest framework, Additional checks and saves in ViewSet and return different response depends on condition

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm making voting. All user can vote 1 time in 24 hours. 
User making vote with POST request.
Every time he vote I want to check the last time he voted:

- if he voted more than 24 hours ago I want to save his vote.
- if less than 24 hours I want to return bad request (or something like this).

**UPDATE.** There were just stupid syntax error in my code — that's not interesting to anybody. So I delete my wrong code and left this post Just for the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you better to use [object-level-validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

```
class VoteAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        exclude =('id','created_date','user',)

    def validate(self, data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        vote_date = request.user.profile.vote_date
        if vote_date + timedelta(days=1) > timezone.now():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You need wait to vote again")
        return data
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really much better solution than I did.

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You have curly brackets (`{}`) after your `if` statement in `perform_create`. Remove those because they are not used in Python to mark the boundaries of a statement/function etc.

Comment: Thanks you are right. There were a lot of errors, I've alrady found it when saw your answer, but thank you anywhere. 
I wasn't sure I've making this right way from the beginning, now I've fix all errors and it works, so I'm  posting the hole working code here as an answer.

Comment: @yestema Consider following Bear Brown's suggestion as well!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I finally solve this problem. There was a lot of syntax errors Update code to correct version. May be somebody will need it so I've put it here:
But there is the better solution below from **Bear Brown**

**views.py:**

```
class VoteAddViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VoteAddSerializer
    http_method_names = ['post',]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)
        allow_vote_date = profile.vote_date + timedelta(days=1)
        if (allow_vote_date < timezone.now()):
            profile.vote_date = timezone.now()
            profile.save()
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class VoteAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Vote
    exclude =('id','created_date','user',)
```

**urls.py:**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'vote_add', views.VoteAddViewSet, 'vote_add')
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^', include(router.urls)),]
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    vote_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)

class Girl (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    pic =  models.ImageField(upload_to='girls/pic1/', blank=True, default=None)

class Vote (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='girls_user_voted_for', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    girl = models.ForeignKey(Girl, null=True, blank=True, related_name='supporters_of_this_girl', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.id)
```